# Avoid inserting exponential value in DB Float column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, insert, floating-point

I have a table like

```
CONTACT

Name                           Null     Type                                                                                                                                                                                          
------------------------------ -------- -----------
CONTACT_ID                     NOT NULL NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
NAME                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(45)                                                                                                                                                                                  
EMAIL                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(45)                                                                                                                                                                                  
ADDRESS                        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(45)                                                                                                                                                                                  
TELEPHONE                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(45)                                                                                                                                                                                  
AMOUNT                         NOT NULL FLOAT(126)
```

and the insert statement is:

```
Insert into  contact("CONTACT_ID","NAME","EMAIL","ADDRESS","TELEPHONE","AMOUNT")
values ('36','babusailesh1117777','hainatu1@gmail.com','Vietnam1',
  '0904277091','0.0000000555559080767');
```

When I see the final value inserted in the database, I see an exponential value.

How can I avoid this at database level for all tables?

Comment: Yes. I did. But no change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't stored as an exponential, it's stored in Oracle's internal number representation. When you query it, it's displayed with your sessions's current number format:

```
select 0.0000000555559080767 from dual;

                  0.0000000555559080767
---------------------------------------
                                5.6E-08
```

Which you can override in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer:

```
set numformat 999.9999999999999999999
select 0.0000000555559080767 from dual;

   0.0000000555559080767
------------------------
    .0000000555559080767
```

Or explicitly format the value as a string, for display only:

```
set numf ""
select to_char(0.0000000555559080767, '9990.9999999999999999999') from dual;

TO_CHAR(0.000000055555908
-------------------------
    0.0000000555559080767
```

If you have a client application retrieving and using the value then it should query it as a float, into a suitable data type for the client's language, and then it's up to the client how it's displayed.

---

You also shouldn't be inserting a string into the float column, that just does an implicit conversion; the last argument in your insert should  be `0.0000000555559080767` rather than the quoted `'0.0000000555559080767'`.

Comment: Agreed that i should not be using single quotes.
However when i run set numformat 999.9999999999999999999, i get ORacle error ORA-00922

Comment: From which client? If it isn't one of the two I mentioned you might need to change the preferences some other way.

Comment: Oracle SQL developer: version 1.0.0.12
Anyways i will try to connect via command prompt to DB using sqlplus.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Works using direct connect to oracle without using tools like SQL developer etc

Comment: That's an ancient version of SQL Developer. It's works on all the recent versions I've used; current is 4.1.

Comment: Alex, can you please answer this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126882/oracle-setting-up-a-globalization-support-environment

Answer (score 0):

This is a function of *the way the value is displayed*, not what is being stored in the database. The database just stores a numeric float value, and whatever retrieves and displays the data decides how to display that.  The exponential value you mention is common for displaying such floating point numbers.

You can have Oracle return a string formatted in a way for display using a function such as [`to_char`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm), that allows you to set formatting.  However, it may make more sense to handle this in whatever program or code is using the database.

Also note that floating point numbers have limited precision, so if you need to get that exact number string back, a float is not the way to go.