# Oracle Setting Up a Globalization Support Environment

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

We want to set this `SET NUMFORMAT 99999999999999999.00` at the user/schema level, for all sessions. Currently ,when set this command , it is getting applicable for that session only. Can we do this globally , so that when ever we open the connection , this works >

Comment: This is a client setting. Which client? If SQL\*Plus and always running from the same machine then you can via login.sql/glogin.sql, for example; other clients may allow it too. But it applies to all numbers - it's better to include the formatting in the query so it's specific and appropriate to each value - if you want a string representation, specify what you want it to look like. But only for display, and application running the query should get the actual number back, and it should decide how to display it.

Answer (score 0):

**SET NUMFORMAT** is a **SQL*Plus** command. In general, it is a **client-side** setting to **display** the number.

You could always store the `SQL*Plus` settings in `login.sql` and `glogin.sql`. Whenever `SQL*Plus` starts up, it looks for a file named glogin.sql under the directory `$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin`. If such a file is found, it is read and the containing statements are executed. Additionally, after reading glogin.sql, sql*plus also looks for a file named login.sql in the directory from where `SQL*Plus` was and in the directory that the environment variable SQLPATH points to and reads it and executes it. Settings from the login.sql take precedence over settings from glogin.sql.

If you are just displaying the number, and want it to be displayed in desired format, then use **TO_CHAR** at **individual SQL statement level**.

For example,

```
SQL> select to_char(123.456,'999.9') VALUE from dual
  2  /

VALUE
------
 123.5
```

Bottomline, this is a `SQL*Plus` command, not an Oracle **SQL** or **PL/SQL** command. This will only affect how the data is displayed from `SQL*Plus`, not from other programs that access the database. There should be something similar in whatever you are using to display your data instead of `SQL*Plus`.

Comment: I want to do that kind of generic settings and then login and then do insert into table command.

Comment: Insert statement has nothing to do with any formatting. Oracle stores numbers in variable-length. It is not stored the way you see when displayed on a client. So no need to worry about formatting while inserting. You just need the format while displaying, which I have already answered.