# Extracting a number from database SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to extract a number from my database but since the number is long I only get `3.9E+17` instead of `39595556655558918`

Comment: Column data type? Target data type?

Comment: That's you SQL client _displaying_ the number (assuming it **is** a `number` column) that way. The number itself is store without any formatting in the database

Comment: it is a number column but is there any way i can display the whole number

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34765887/266304). Which client are you using?

Comment: If you're using SQL*Plus, try 'set numformat 999,999,999,999,999,999'.

Comment: i'm using sqldeveloper

Comment: Works for me https://imgur.com/a/UybubDD

Comment: I used select to_char(column) from table and it worked :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - run that as a script rather than as a command *8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How a number is displayed depends on the settings of the tool you are using, and how it is configured. But you can convert the number to a string yourself and control the conversion:

```
CREATE TABLE t (n NUMBER);
INSERT INTO t (n) VALUES (39595556655558918);

SELECT TO_CHAR(n, '999999999999999999') FROM t;
39595556655558918
```

For a list of letters that can be used in the format string (the 9999... in the example), have a look at [Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-DFB23985-2943-4C6A-96DF-DF0F664CED96) in Oracle's SQL Language Reference.

Answer (score -2):

Try Convert(varchar(150),column Name)

Comment: The question is tagged for Oracle. This isn't valid.